# -webkit-transform rotate without float attribute

Tags: jquery, css, webkit, transform

I am trying to use a double right-angle quote (`&raquo;`) as a dropdown indicator. I have it working in my navigation where there is a `float: right;` assigned to it. Outside of the navigation however, when I don't have a `float:` assigned to it, it doesn't rotate. I am rotating the arrow with jQuery & CSS3 by adding a class `down` to the `<span>` element the right-angle quote is wrapped in.

Here is the `down` css class that gets added to rotate the arrows:

```
.drop-arrows.down {
    /* FF Chrome Opera etc */
    -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg) !important; 
    -moz-transform: rotate(90deg) !important;
    -o-transform: rotate(90deg) !important;
    /* IE */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=3);
}
```

That class is added upon activation of the dropdown via jQuery. The only issue is this doesn't work without a `float` added to the arrow container as well, which is very confusing to me.

Here is the HTML wrapping the arrow:

```
<a id='filter-trigger' href='javascript:void(0);'>FILTERS <span class='drop-arrows'>&raquo;</span></a>
```

Does `-webkit-transform` require a float to work? Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: try position: relative;

Comment: On which element? I applied it to the `.drop-arrows` and `.drop-arrows.down` classes but there were no results.

Comment: Sorry, it was absolute. Added answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need to set position absolute

```
.drop-arrows {
    position: absolute;
    /* FF Chrome Opera etc */
    -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg) !important; 
    -moz-transform: rotate(90deg) !important;
    -o-transform: rotate(90deg) !important;
    /* IE */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=3);
}
```